# kernel version in boot folder

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

When I enter "ls" command in the boot folder, the below kernels are shown:
 kernel-3.16-lts-x86_64-all,  kernel-4.14-lts-x86_64-all,  kernel-4.19-lts-x86_64-all,  kernel-4.9-lts-x86_64-all

What does "all" mean? If my machine is using the "kernel-3.16-lts-x86_64-all" now, can I say that it's running on all 3.16.* versions? Can I say that I'm running kernel 3.16.7 for instance?

I asked this question because I have to apply some patches which are designed for the specific kernel (3.16.7), I'm wondering whether it is correct to apply these patches when I have "kernel-3.16-lts-x86_64-all" or not.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you ask a question which makes reference to the contents of a directory, I would recommend posting the output of `ls` verbatim into the question, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for help; the listing of filename parts only can lead to confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are [Open Network Linux](http://opennetlinux.org/) [kernels](https://github.com/opencomputeproject/OpenNetworkLinux/tree/master/packages/base/amd64/kernels), and the directory names are split up as follows:

- `3.16-lts` etc.: [the subdirectory](https://github.com/opencomputeproject/OpenNetworkLinux/tree/master/packages/base/any/kernels) tracking a given suite of releases;
- `x86_64-all`: [the subdirectory](https://github.com/opencomputeproject/OpenNetworkLinux/tree/master/packages/base/any/kernels/3.16-lts/configs) containing the kernel configuration to use.

`all` in `x86_64-all` means that the kernel configuration is applied to all x86_64 setups; this nomenclature would allow for specific variants if necessary. If your machine is using the 3.16 kernel, it’s running whatever 3.16 series kernel is currently set up — as of now, that’s [3.16.64](https://github.com/opencomputeproject/OpenNetworkLinux/blob/master/packages/base/any/kernels/3.16-lts/kconfig.mk). Each “LTS” (long term support) kernel gets updates for a long time after its initial release; you can see these on [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/).

The `uname -a` output on your system should tell you exactly what release of the kernel you’re running. It might not be 3.16.64, depending on how up-to-date your system is, but it will be newer than 3.16.7 — the first 3.16 kernel in ONL was [3.16.39](https://github.com/opencomputeproject/OpenNetworkLinux/commit/a7a195e2f50f6991d9f011e7534bca8b0c9c8fe1#diff-74fcac25e007f8db4471df6ee01d845b).